# Merge .cpp with .cu file

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

I'm a beginner in CUDA programming and I use VC++ 2010. I'm trying to call a kernel file .cu from a main() function in a .cpp file. Now I can't merge these two because they are different projects and solutions. Can you please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say simply copy code from one project to another?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put them in the same project. In msvc10, you have the option to add a .cuh or .cu file (that way it is automatically set up so that nvcc will compile the specific file, and only the binaries? will be linked in the end)

A picture says a million words:
[image: a]